# Calculating these derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

The problem states,

> Find the derivative of each of the following functions.
>
> $\textbf{(1)}$ Let $F:[0,5] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$F(x) = \int_{1}^{x}t^2dt$$ for all $x \in [0,5]$
>
> $\textbf{(2)}$ Let $G:[1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$G(x) = \int_{1}^{x^2}(t^5 + 7)dt$$ for all $x \in [1,2]$

Here is my attempt: $\textbf{(1)}$ Let $h:[0,5] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by, for $m \in [0,5]$, $h(m) = m^2$. As $h$ is continuous on $[0,5]$, it is therefore integrable. Consider $H:[0,5] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by, for $k \in [0,5]$, $H(k) = \int_{0}^kh(t)dt$. By the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have that for all $k \in [0,5]$, $H'(k) = h(k)$.
Now let $p \in [0,5]$. Then $\int_{0}^ph(t)dt = \int_{0}^1h(t)dt + \int_{1}^ph(t)dt$, so that $$F(p) = \int_{1}^ph(t)dt = \int_{0}^ph(t)dt - \int_{0}^1h(t)dt = H(p) - \int_{0}^1h(t)dt.$$ One may calculate, either via direct definition or using the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, that $\int_{0}^{1}h(t)dt = 1/3$ so that for all $p \in [0,5]$, we have $F(p) = H(p) -1/3$.
Hence, $F'(p) = (H(p) - 1/3)' = H'(p) = h(p)$ so that $F' = h$.

$\textbf{(2)}$ Consider $j:[1,4] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by, for $q \in [1,4]$, $j(q) = q^5 + 7$. Consider also $J:[1,4] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by, for $k \in [1,4]$, $J(k) = \int_{1}^kj(k)dk$.
Let $s:[1,2] \rightarrow [1,4]$ be defined by, for $e \in [1,2]$, $s(e) = e^2$.
Then for all $e \in [1,2]$, $$G(e) = \int_{1}^{e^2}j(e)de = J(e^2) = J(s(e)) = J\circ s(e)$$ so that $G'(e) =(J\circ s)'(e) = J'(s(e))s'(e) = j(s(e))(2e) = ((e^2)^5 + 7)(2e) = 2e^{11}+ 14e$.

Comment: Looks  long but correct .

Comment: It looks right but, why haven't you applied the first theorem of calculus directly to $F$ and $H$?

Comment: Why are there so many  new variables and functions in your attempt? Just write $F'(x) =x^2$ and $G'(x) = 2x((x^2)^5+7)$ via FTC and chain rule.